# Pandas groupby: get best zscore for counts() of each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics

I have a pandas groupby object that returns the counts of each gene type, roughly as shown below (column headers formatted manually for clarity):

```
counts = df.groupby(["ID", "Gene"]).size()

counts
ID      Gene      Count
1_1_1   SMARCB1     1
        smad       12
1_1_10  SMARCB1     2
        smad       17
1_1_100 SMARCB1     3
```

I need to get the within group zscore, and then return the Gene with the highest zscore.

I've tried the following, but it seems to be calculating zscores across the whole dataset and does not return the correct zscore:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
counts = df.groupby(["ID", "Match"]).size().pipe(zscore)
```

I've tried with transform and gotten the same results.

I tried:

```
counts = match_df.groupby(["ID", "Match"]).size().apply(zscore)
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Whatever I try, it doesn't give the correct output. The zscores for the first two lines should be [-1,1] in which case I would return the row for 1_1_1 SMARCB1. Etc. Thanks!

## Update

Thanks to help from @ZaxR and switching to numpy mean and standard deviation, I was able to solve this as shown below. This solution also provides a summary dataframe of the raw counts and zscores for each gene:

```
# group by id and gene match and sum hits to each molecule
counts = df.groupby(["ID", "Match"]).size()

# calculate zscore by feature for molecule counts
# features that only align to one molecule are given a score of 1
zscore = lambda x: (x - np.mean(x)) / np.std(x) 
zscores = counts.groupby('ID').apply(zscore).fillna('1').to_frame('Zscore')

# group results back together with counts and output to 
# merge with positions and save to file 
zscore_df = zscores.reset_index()
zscore_df.columns = ["ID", "Match", "Zscore"]
count_df = counts.reset_index()
count_df.columns = ["ID", "Match", "Counts"]
zscore_df["Counts"] = count_df["Counts"]

# select gene with best zscore meeting threshold
max_df = zscore_df[zscore_df.groupby('ID')['Zscore'].transform(max) \
                       == zscore_df['Zscore']]
```

Comment: mmm away from my computer but try `.groupby(['FeautreID','Match'], as_index=False).size().groupby(['FeatureID','Match']).apply(zscore)`

Comment: Thank you, but I need to first get the counts to compute the zscores on.

Comment: Yep, just realized that, try my edit (after fixing any typos that might have snuck in, I'm on my phone)

Comment: Thanks for the quick edit. I tried to make it work, but its only returning NaNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason *why* `df.groupby(["ID", "Gene"]).size().transform(zscore)` doesn't work is because the last group is a series with only one item,  so when you try to apply the lambda function zscore to a single [integer], you get the `'int' object has no attribute 'mean'` error. Note that x.mean() behaves differently than pandas' 'mean'.

## Update

I think this should do it:

```
# Setup code
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["1_1_1", "1_1_1", "1_1_10", "1_1_10", "1_1_100"],
                   "Gene": ["SMARCB1", "smad", "SMARCB1", "smad", "SMARCB1"],
                   "Count": [1, 12, 2, 17, 3]})
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'Gene'])

# Add standard deviation for every row
# Note: .transform(zscore) would also work
df['std_dev'] = df.groupby('ID')['Count'].apply(zscore)

# Find the max standard deviation for each group and
# use that as a mask for the original df
df[df.groupby('ID')['std_dev'].transform(max) == df['std_dev']]

Out:
                  Count   std_dev
ID       Gene
1_1_1    smad     12      0.707107
1_1_10   smad     17      0.707107
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned above, transform does not give the correct answer. It seems to be taking not the group zscore, but the population zscore. I'm not sure that's exactly what it's doing, but the answers returned are not correct.

Comment: Sorry I missed that while reading. I added an explanation as to why the transform method doesn't work as an FYI

Comment: After some testing, my answer wasn't quite ideal because I lost the Gene information. I have also been trying to figure out how to change the zscore function for this purpose so that if the group size is less than 2, it will return 1 instead of trying to calc a zscore: 

zscore = lambda x: stats.zscore(x) if len(x) > 1 else 1

But that doesn't want to work either :/

Comment: Thanks for the update. The standard deviation step is returning nothing but NaN :(

Comment: I just added the setup code I used and it works perfectly for me on pandas 0.23. What version of pandas are you running?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @ZaxR. You led me to the solution, which I've posted above.